# Javascript change background color of svg g path element

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to change the style of the following element:

```
<path d="M0 573.96 L0 595.28 L64.96 595.28 L64.96 573.96 L0 573.96 L0 573.96 Z" class="st8"/>
```

Full svg code:

```
<g id="shape487-256" v:mID="487" v:groupContext="shape" transform="translate(707.533,-425.236)">
            <title>Sheet.487</title>
            <desc>Claims Management</desc>
            <v:textBlock v:margins="rect(4,4,4,4)" v:tabSpace="42.5197"/>
            <v:textRect cx="32.478" cy="584.619" width="64.96" height="21.314"/>
            <path d="M0 573.96 L0 595.28 L64.96 595.28 L64.96 573.96 L0 573.96 L0 573.96 Z" class="st8"/>
            <text x="21.21" y="582.22" class="st9" v:langID="1033"><v:paragraph v:horizAlign="1"/><v:tabList/>Claims <tspan
                        x="9.92" dy="1.2em" class="st10">Management</tspan></text>      </g>
```

I only managed to change the stroke of the text but not the background color. Simply setting fill does not have an effect, so I want to remove the st8 class but I get the message path.removeAttribute is not a function.

```
function highlightTrend01(){
    //Claims Management
    var e = document.getElementById("shape487-256");
    // e.setAttribute("stroke","blue"); setting stroke works
    var paths = e.getElementsByTagName("path");
    paths.removeAttribute("class");
    paths.style["fill"] = "orange";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove a class, use :

```
paths.classList.remove("st8");
```

it will not remove the attribute but that doesnt matter in this case i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to change the background color by selecting the right child element, more elegant solutions highly appreciated.

```
function highlightTrend01(){
    //Claims Management
    var e = document.getElementById("shape487-256");
    // e.setAttribute("stroke","blue"); setting stroke works
    var children = e.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var c = children[i];
        // console.log(c);
        // var cId = c.getAttribute("id");
        var attrClass = c.getAttribute("class");
        if (c.tagName == "path" && attrClass == "st8"){
            console.log("Tag name: " + c.tagName +  " class: " + attrClass);
            // c.removeAttribute("class");
            c.style["fill"] = "orange"
        }
    }

}
```